# How do surgeons select which fixation method to use?

Tags: orthopedics, bone-fractures, tibia, x-rays

For bone fractures, there are many different internal fixation methods to choose from when attempting to treat the injury. How do surgeons or the people responsible know which method provides more stability? For example, for the case in the picture, you could use a combination of plates, screws and rods for internal fixation. How do you choose the optimal method?[image]